# INDEXEDDB update/put not returning updated object in the expected state

Tags: javascript, php, indexeddb

I have an INDEXEDDB database that i've created with two object stores: 'games' and 'plays' (in reference to football).  I am letting IDB create the keys for each store via 'autoincrement'.  The 'games' store can have multiple games and likewise, there will be multiple plays for each game.  Later, i export these stores via JSON to PHP and am attempting to correlate the plays that took place in game 1 (for example) to that game and so on.  I am using a 'foreign key'-like value (a gameID attribute) in the plays store to indicate that the play goes with a certain game.  However, upon JSON export of the two stores, i have found that the 'games' store does not have its key value exported and therefore, i cannot for sure connect a play (which has a reference to 'gameID') to a particular game (which does not contain the reference within its structure).

So, i thought the answer to be simple:  create a value called 'gameID' within the 'game' store and once i have that id, update the record in the store with the gameID value.

The problem is that i've written IDB 'update' code or 'put' code which seems to be 'successful', yet when i go get the game in question later, the value is not correct.  I'm finding that my updates are not updating the data structures as i would expect to see them in Chrome Developer tools.  Below is an example of what i am talking about:

[Object in question in Chrome Developer tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kQavq.jpg)

Above you can see graphically the issue and i'm not sure what is happening.  You'll see that in the areas marked "A" and "C", there are the updated values listed (i do a similar update later to mark a game 'complete' at the end of a game).  However, the actual data structure in IDB (indicated with "B") shows the old values that i "thought" that i'd updated successfully.  So, i'm not at all sure how to read this structure in Chrome Developer, which seems to report the updates that were made separately from the object itself.

I've tried doing this update thru passing the gameID in question and via cursor.

```
function putGameID (conn, thisGameID) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const tx = conn.transaction(['gamesList'], 'readwrite');
        const gameStore = tx.objectStore(['gamesList']); 
        const gameRequest = gameStore.get(thisGameID);
        gameRequest.onsuccess = () => {
            const game = gameRequest.result;
            game.gameID = thisGameID;
            console.log({game});
            const updateGameRequest = gameStore.put(game);
            updateGameRequest.onsuccess = () => {
                console.log("Successfully updated this game ID.");
                resolve(updateGameRequest.onsuccess);
            }
etc....
```

It appears the record was updated, just not in the manner i would expect.
I've also attempted this using a cursor update to similar effect:

```
function putGameID (conn, thisGameID) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const tx = conn.transaction(['gamesList'], 'readwrite');
        const gameStore = tx.objectStore(['gamesList']); 

        gameStore.openCursor().onsuccess = function(event) {
            const cursor = event.target.result;
            if (cursor) {
                if (!cursor.value.gameID) {
                    const updatedGame = cursor.value;
                    updatedGame.gameID = thisGameID;
                    const request = cursor.update(updatedGame);
                    cursor.continue;
                }
            }
        }
etc.....
```

Can someone help me to understand:
(1) how to read the structure in the CDT?  Why are the updated values not part of the object's structure?
and ...
(2) how can i modify my approach to get the results that i wish to achieve?

As per requested, this is the code that originally creates the two object stores and it is called upon entry into the form:

```
async function idbConnect(name, version) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const request = indexedDB.open(DBName, DBVersion);

        request.onupgradeneeded = function(event) {
            //if (!request.objectStoreNames.contains('gamesList')) {
                console.log('Doing indexeddb upgrade');
                db = request.result;
                /*Create the two stores - plays and games. */
                
                playObjectStore = db.createObjectStore('playsList',{keyPath: "id", autoIncrement:true});
                gameObjectStore = db.createObjectStore('gamesList',{keyPath: "gameID", autoIncrement:true});
    
                /* Create indexes */
                playObjectStore.createIndex("playIDIdx","id", {unique:false});
                playObjectStore.createIndex("gamePlayIDIdx","gameID", {unique:false});
                playObjectStore.createIndex("playCreatedDateIdx","createdDate", {unique:false});
                gameObjectStore.createIndex("gameIDIdx","gameID", {unique:true});
                gameObjectStore.createIndex("gameCreatedDateIdx","createdDate", {unique:false});
                //return db;
            //}

        }
        request.onsuccess = () => resolve(request.result);
        request.onerror = () => reject(request.error);
        request.onblocked = () => { console.log('blocked'); };
    });
}
```

This code makes the call to add the game:

```
try {
        conn = await idbConnect(DBName,DBVersion);
        game = await addGameIDB(conn);
        // Understand what is going on in the line below.
        //Saving the game ID to populate.
        globalGameID = game.gameID;
        // Here is where i'm attempting to update the gameID....
        await putGameID(conn, globalGameID);
        console.log({globalGameID});
```

Once the stores are created, the following code adds a game:

```
function addGameIDB(conn) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // some irrelevant stuff to format dates, etc....
    let newGame = [
            {
                gameID:         null, // What i'd like to populate....
                gameDate:       thisGameDate,
                gameTime:       thisGameTime,
                team1Name:      thisTeamOne,
                team2Name:      thisTeamTwo,
                gameCompleted:  false,
                createdDate:    d
            }    
        ];    

        db = conn.transaction('gamesList','readwrite');
        let gameStore = db.objectStore('gamesList');
        let gameRequest = gameStore.add(newGame);

        gameRequest.onsuccess = (ev) => {
            console.log('Successfully inserted an game object');
            const newGameRequest =              gameStore.get(gameRequest.result);
            newGameRequest.onsuccess = () => {
                resolve(newGameRequest.result);
            } 
        };
    
        gameRequest.onerror = (err) => {
            console.log('error attempting to insert game object' + err);
            reject(gameRequest.error);
        }

    });
```

Comment: Nitpick: tx.objectStore() takes a name, not an array of names. You're getting lucky because that array stringifies to a name.

Comment: The devtools display seems to be showing that the value that was originally put into the database was an array containing an object, rather than just the object, which could explain what you're seeing. Can you share the original population code and verify what you're populating the store with?

Comment: sure can, here's the current code that creates a game and also when a game is created, i'm creating the plays store as well....

Comment: I agree with your assessment.  There could (and will be) multiple games, but it appears that my updates are creating an array of changes attached to the object rather than updating the object itself?  I'm new to INDEXEDDB but i'm a tad baffled as to why.  Thanks for any advice you can give.

Comment: Re: Joshua's comment about tx.objectStore.... i am not sure if i understand the comment.  'gamesList' is the name of a single object store, not an array.  The store itself does contain an array of 'games' but it is a single object store within the IDB.

Comment: It looks like the code has been changed since I made that comment.

Comment: you're initializing newGame to an array (`let newGame = [ ... ];`); put() adds a single JS value as a record. So you're adding a record which is an array, not the object inside the array. When you're applying updates e.g. `updatedGame.gameID = ...;` that's adding a property to the record... which is an array, not the object inside the array.